# I want to check if a string matches a format

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if a `string` matches the following format:

```
"text|text|text"
```

There should be no `whitespace` in the `String`, only 2 numbers before the dash and 2 numbers after the dash.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I see no dashes in that string.  And is text supposed to be any text?

Answer (score 1):

Java `String` has a method `matches(String regex)` that can be called to run a regular expression on the String and returns a boolean.

```
String regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\|[a-zA-Z0-9]+\|[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"
String myString = "text|text|text";

myString.matches(regex); // true
"test".matches(regex); // false
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you're looking for but I didn't have enough space to leave this as a comment. If you're aiming to just make sure that there is no whitespace and there are only two '|' symbols, using the substring() and indexOf() methods from the String class should help.

indexOf(String) - Finds the index of the first letter of a given String within a bigger String

substring(int begin, int end) - returns a snipped version of the string of characters indexed between begin and (end - 1)

`public boolean matchesFormat(String s) {
    if (s.indexOf(" ") == -1) { // First we use the String class's indexOf method to make sure we have no spaces anywhere in the string
        if (s.indexOf("|") != -1) { // Now we check to make sure we have at least one '|' symbol
            String cut = s.substring(s.indexOf("|") + 1, s.length()); // indexOf() only returns the index of the first appearance of the | symbol. We'll have to cut the string to remove the first and check for the second
            if (cut.indexOf("|") != -1) {
                cut = cut.substring(cut.indexOf("|") + 1, cut.length());
                if (cut.indexOf("|") == -1) { // here we make sure we have two and only two | symbols
                    return true; // because now we have determined that this string meets the criteria
            }

        }
    }
    return false; because the previous algorithm was unable to prove this string to follow the criteria
}`